# Unable to verify the first certificate when ionic start using command prompt

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I getting below error while create new project using cmd

```
D:\IONIC>ionic start myProject tutorial
× Downloading and extracting tutorial starter - failed!
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1103:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:637:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:467:38)
```

Below the versions the I am using,

```
D:\IONIC>ionic -v
3.19.1
D:\IONIC>npm -v
5.6.0
D:\IONIC>cordova -v
8.0.0
```

can anyone please help me for this error?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get round this by doing a temporary set of an environment variable before running the ionic scaffolding. *set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0*. Don't really like it a solution but managed to get me over the line.